# Ejecutar jar creado con openjdk haciendo docle click en windows 10

Tags: java, windows10, jar

estoy intentando pasarme a OpenJdk. Tengo instalada la última versión:

openjdk version "14.0.2" 2020-07-14

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 14.0.2+12-46)

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.2+12-46, mixed mode, sharing)

Mi problema es que puedo ejecutar los archivos jar creados con openjdk desde consola, pero no lo puedo hacer desde el explorador de windows haciendo clic en los archivos jar.

Esto es lo que si funcion, compliada en cualquier versión de 8 a 14 las probé todas: "java -jar miappcompliadaconopenjdk.jar"
''
La pregunta en si es como asociar los archivos jar para que sean abiertos con openjdk haciendo doble click en ellos?

Desde ya muchas gracias.

*Edito:

Tal vez sirva como ayuda para aclarar mi consulta. Pude ejecutar desde el explorador de windows haciendo un acceso directo a java.exe que esta en el directorio bin del openJDK pasando como parámetro -jar y la ubicaciçon del archivo. Pero me lo abre junto con una ventana de consola. Mi idea es que abra solo la aplicación,sin consola.

Lo hice cambiando en el acceso directo Destino: "C:\Program Files\Java\openjdk-14.0.2\bin\java.exe" -jar C:\14MiApp.jar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay dos cosas importantes que saber aquí:

la primera es que el programa `Java.exe` siempre abre una consola, así que la alternativa es usar el programa que viene en la misma carpeta llamado `javaw.exe` que es exactamente igual pero no abre una consola como te lo indica la [documentación oficial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html).

Lo segundo es que puedes asociar este programa con la extensión `.jar` siguiendo [los siguientes pasos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511063/how-to-run-jar-file-by-double-click-on-windows-7-64-bit):

1. Ir a panel de control (mi compu está en inglés así que de ahora en más te diré los nombres en inglés, en este caso es Control Panel)
2. Ir a programas por defecto (Default Programs)
3. Darle click en la opción para asociar tipos de archivos con un programa específico (Associate a file type or protocol with a specific program)
4. Seleccionar jar
5. Buscar el programa para correrlo, en tu caso: C:\Program Files\Java\openjdk-14.0.2\bin\javaw.exe

Listo, cierra las ventanas y de ahora en más deberían de abrirse con doble click.

Comment: Muchas Gracias. Me ha servido de mucho la información. Ahora he creado un acceso directo a javaw.exe con las mismas características de el que apuntaba a java.exe. Ya no me abre la consola y la aplicación funciona correctamente. Con esto ya puedo seguir adelante. No he podido asociar las exenciones jar a javax.jar. Bueno, si he podido. Pero no funciona correctamente, pienso que sera porque le falta el parámetro "-jar"  que pongo en el destino del acceso directo.